# Create column names based on "by" argument the data.table way

Tags: r, data.table

Say I have the following data.table

```
dt <- data.table(var = c("a", "b"), val = c(1, 2))
```

Now I want to add two new columns to `dt`, named `a`, and `b` with the respective values (1, 2). I can do this with a loop, but I want to do it the data.table way.

The result would be a `data.table` like this:

```
dt.res <- data.table(var = c("a", "b"), val = c(1, 2), #old vars 
                     a = c(1, NA), b = c(NA, 2)) # newly created vars
```

So far I came up with something like this

```
dt[, c(xx) := val, by = var]
```

where `xx` would be a `data.table`-command similar to `.N` which addresses the value of the `by`-group.

Thanks for the help!

**Appendix: The for-loop way**

The non-data.table-way with a `for`-loop instead of a `by`-argument would look something like this:

```
for (varname in dt$var){
     dt[var == varname, c(varname) := val]
}
```

Comment: Try `dt[, c('a', 'b') := Map('*', lapply(var, function(x) val[NA^(x!=var)]), val)]`

Comment: The bigger picture would be nice to see.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to write a function that takes dates of financial transaction constructs a portfolio out of this information. The question concerns a part of the function where the number of stocks held in the portfolio is calculated.
For example, stock "a" is held with a quantity of 1 and stock "b" with a quantity of 2. 
The next steps are merging the data.table with another one, containing the prices and multiplying the values to get the portfolio value.
Does that help in any way?

Comment: What's wrong with `dt[, ':='(var1=val1, var2=val2...) ]` ? Do you need to generate or pass the names programmatically?

Comment: I don't understand *"`xx` would be a data.table-command similar to `.N` which addresses the value of the by-group"*. Can you give an example? Do you want to form the variable name vector in xx based on the names in the by-argument? Please give an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the example showed, we can use `dcast` from the `data.table` to convert the long format to wide, and join with the original dataset `on` the 'val' column.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
dt[dcast(dt, val~var, value.var='val'), on='val']
#   var val  a  b
#1:   a   1  1 NA
#2:   b   2 NA  2
```

Or as @CathG mentioned in the comments, for previous versions either `merge` or set the key column and then join.

```
merge(dt, dcast.data.table(dt, val~var, value.var='val'))
```

Comment: or `library(reshape2); merge(dt, dcast(dt, val~var, value.var='val'))` with former versions of data.table

Comment: ...If this is the answer, the question needs restating. The changing to wide-form and merge/join/dcast is part of the question.